# Не работает выход из профиля в плагине Office (MODx Revolution)

Tags: modx

такая проблема: когда жму кнопку «Выход» в профиле на сайте, то происходит перенаправление на страницу для не авторизованных пользователей, но когда жму на кнопку профиля, то все равно открывается профиль пользователя, а не страница авторизации, т.е. выход из профиля не происходит, разлогиниться можно только через админку завершив все сеансы. Что тут может быть не так? Ниже представлены вызовы сниппетов (вызов снипетов происходит из одноименных шаблонов, а не через контент, но у ресурса html-редактор отключен):
Авторизация:

```
[[!officeAuth?
   &tplLogin=`Office.auth.login`
   &tplLogout=`tpl.Office.auth.logout`
   &tplActivate=`tpl.Office.auth.activate`
   &tplRegister=`tpl.Office.auth.register`
   &rememberme=`0`
   &HybridAuth=`0`
   &logoutResourceId=`1` //Главная страинца
   &loginResourceId=`23` //Страница личного кабинета
 ]]
```

Регистрация:

```
[[!officeAuth?
   &tplLogin=`Office.auth.reg`
   &tplActivate=`tpl.Office.auth.activate`
   &tplRegister=`tpl.Office.auth.register`
   &HybridAuth=`0`
   &logoutResourceId=`1`
 ]]
```

Профиль (вызов происходит через контентную часть ресурса)

```
 [[!officeProfile?
  &HybridAuth=`0`
 ]]
 [[!officeMiniShop2?
  &cartLink=`13`
 ]]
```

История заказов(вызов происходит через контентную часть ресурса)

```
 [[!officeProfile?
  &HybridAuth=`0`
 ]]
 [[!officeMiniShop2?
  &cartLink=`13`
 ]]
```

Ресурсы "Профиль" и "История заказов" находятся в ресурсе "Личный кабинет", который является ссылкой.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил включнием дружественных URL в системных натсройках MODx